# Dual Boot- Booting into System Reserve

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

TL:DR i did a thing now its booting off of system reserve

long version: I was having issue with Ubuntu so i used boot-repair just general unstable issues

then when i decided to go and play on windows it gave me the option to boot into 2 version of windows
booting into sda1 will work until it runs out of space and then just crash

attempting to boot into sda2 will give a message stating that bootmgn is missing press ctr-alt-delete to restart

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRZNi.jpg

I am new to linux and dualbooting so things like "are you in uefi or legacy" scare me and confuse me

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Windows 7 (possibly Windows Vista as well), a separate 100mb partition containing the windows bootloader exists on the hard drive. That system reserved space is that bootloader. As for it running out of space, that shouldn't be happening. Go into Ubuntu and pull up a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T), and type `sudo update-grub` at the prompt. It will ask you for your password. Enter it. Keep in mind that no dots will display, just press enter when you are done and it will execute. After that runs, your Ubuntu bootloader will update and you should only have one entry for Windows.

Comment: after doing this it shows only /dev/sda1 which is the system reserve

Comment: That's the one you want, that's the Windows bootloader. Windows stores its bootloader in the system reserve so that's the one you have to go to for it to work.